# Corrupted C drive Windows 8.1 Lenovo laptop

Tags: windows-8, thinkpad

I have a Windows 8.1 Lenovo Thinkpad (For school) and I corrupted my C drive so now it is effectively read only due to the corruption. Will I need to buy a new computer of will re-installing Windows fix this issue. I have already used check disk and a Linux USB but the check disk did nothing and Linux told me the drive was corrupted and couldn't be accessed

Please help me I want to know what I need to do

Comment: What do you mean when you say *I corrupted my C drive*. You can format you entire hard disk and go ahead with installation of Windows (If you have genuine copy with you) or you can try to install Linux. You need not buy a new one

Answer (score -1):

Many Lenovo computers have a "Novo" button on the side of the chassis which is designed to automatically re-install your computer to its original out of the box factory state. Of course you may lose your personal data, but perhaps you already have backups of your Documents folder, etc.